# -bash: cfssl: command not found

Tags: go

When I tried to install [cfssl](https://github.com/cloudflare/cfssl) with this command:

```
go get -u github.com/cloudflare/cfssl/cmd/cfssl
```

I received following output:

```
# github.com/cloudflare/cfssl/crypto/pkcs7
go_packages/src/github.com/cloudflare/cfssl/crypto/pkcs7/pkcs7.go:141: pkcs7.ContentType.String undefined (type asn1.ObjectIdentifier has no field or method String)
# github.com/cloudflare/cfssl/helpers/derhelpers
go_packages/src/github.com/cloudflare/cfssl/helpers/derhelpers/derhelpers.go:16: undefined: crypto.Signer
# github.com/cloudflare/cfssl/csr
go_packages/src/github.com/cloudflare/cfssl/csr/csr.go:191: undefined: x509.CertificateRequest
go_packages/src/github.com/cloudflare/cfssl/csr/csr.go:204: undefined: x509.CreateCertificateRequest
# golang.org/x/crypto/ocsp
go_packages/src/golang.org/x/crypto/ocsp/ocsp.go:494: undefined: crypto.Signer
# github.com/cloudflare/cf-tls/tls
go_packages/src/github.com/cloudflare/cf-tls/tls/handshake_client.go:431: undefined: crypto.Signer
```

I really have no clue whether this is harmful or not and has something to do with the usage of this tool. However when I try to use it, I receive this error:

```
-bash: cfssl: Command not found.
```

I never used go but I wanted to use this tool. Do you guys know why this is not working as expected?

**Edit**

output of `go env`

```
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCHAR="6"
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/ubuntu/go"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/lib/go"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/lib/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
TERM="dumb"
CC="gcc"
GOGCCFLAGS="-g -O2 -fPIC -m64 -pthread"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
```

output of `go version`

```
go version go1.2.1 linux/amd64
```

I really don't know why this is the case because I installed [this](https://storage.googleapis.com/golang/go1.4.2.linux-amd64.tar.gz) version.

Comment: update your installation of Go

Comment: @JimB that is the newest installation

Comment: Show the output of `go env` and `go version`.  `crypto.Signer` was added in go1.4. You should be using go1.4.2

Comment: It seems that you have errors in getting cfssl. Because Github page says you need to have Go lang version 1.4 atleast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you have errors in getting [cfssl](https://github.com/cloudflare/cfssl).

Because [Cloudflare's Github page](https://github.com/cloudflare/cfssl#cloudflares-pkitls-toolkit) says you require to have Go lang version 1.4 atleast.

If you download and install go 1.4 and get cfssl, then binary will be created in 
`$GOPATH/bin/cfssl`

Refer $GOPATH variable - [here](https://golang.org/doc/code.html#GOPATH)

Answer (score 0):

**Install Go lang version latest.**

1.yum update

2.wget https://dl.google.com/go/go1.12.linux-amd64.tar.gz

3.tar -xzf go1.12.linux-amd64.tar.gz

4.mv go /usr/local

5.set up environment variables.

```
 5.1.GOROOT is the location where Go package is installed on your system

   export GOROOT=/usr/local/go

 5.2.GOPATH is the location of your work directoryexport 

  export GOPATH=$HOME/your project location

 5.3.Now set the PATH variable to access go binary system wide

   export PATH=$GOPATH/bin:$GOROOT/bin:$PATH
```

6.verify

```
6.1.go version

6.2.go env
```

**CFSSL**

1.git clone https://github.com/cloudflare/cfssl.git 
$GOPATH/src/github.com/cloudflare/cfssl

2.cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/cloudflare/cfssl

3.make

4.yum install tree

6.tree bin

7.go get -u github.com/cloudflare/cfssl/cmd/...

Comment: when i use the cmd `make` i  get the following error 

`exec: "gcc": executable file not found in $PATH
Makefile:5: recipe for target 'bin/cfssl' failed
make: *** [bin/cfssl] Error 2`

Comment: Same issue, how did you fix it @AATHITHRAJENDRAN

Comment: I haven't :( @GauraangKhurana

Answer (score 0):

You can use these commmand to install **cfssl** and **cfssljson** on last version. You need only have ***wget*** commmand installed on your OS and type these cmd:

```
yum -y -q install wget
VERSION=$(curl --silent "https://api.github.com/repos/cloudflare/cfssl/releases/latest" | grep '"tag_name"' | sed -E 's/.*"([^"]+)".*/\1/')
VNUMBER=${VERSION#"v"}
wget https://github.com/cloudflare/cfssl/releases/download/${VERSION}/cfssl_${VNUMBER}_linux_amd64 -O cfssl
wget https://github.com/cloudflare/cfssl/releases/download/${VERSION}/cfssljson_${VNUMBER}_linux_amd64 -O cfssljson
chmod +x cfssl
chmod +x cfssljson
mv cfssl /usr/local/bin
mv cfssljson /usr/local/bin
```